# Why use Autolayout/Constraints instead of frame and layoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, autolayout, frame

I've implemented a view controller for my app's launch screen, which can be seen below. I decided to use frames instead of autolayout and I was wondering if there would be any reason to use autolayout/constraints here instead.

I'm not permitting rotation on my app, so I don't see what benefits I would net from constraints, and since I don't like to use interface builder, I think the code is cleaner/easier with creating and laying out frames.

I appreciate any input - please find the code below.

```
#import "LaunchViewController.h"
#import "RegisterTableViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface LaunchViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *appLabel;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *signUpButton;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *loginButton;

@end

@implementation LaunchViewController

#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor standardBlackColor];
    [self layoutViews];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIView

- (void)layoutViews
{
    self.appLabel.frame = [self _appLabelFrame];
    self.loginButton.frame = [self _loginButtonFrame];
    self.signUpButton.frame = [self _signUpButtonFrame];

    [self.view addSubview:self.appLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loginButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.signUpButton];
}

#pragma mark - Layout

- (CGRect)_appLabelFrame
{
    CGFloat x_offset = 0;
    CGFloat y_offset = (self.view.frame.size.height / 10);
    CGFloat width =self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = 50;
    return CGRectMake(x_offset, y_offset, width, height);
}

- (CGRect)_signUpButtonFrame
{
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height/14;
    CGFloat x_offset = self.view.frame.size.width / 24;
    CGFloat y_offset = self.view.frame.size.height - ((height + x_offset));
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width - (2 * x_offset);
    return CGRectMake(x_offset, y_offset, width, height);}

- (CGRect)_loginButtonFrame
{
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height/14;
    CGFloat x_offset = self.view.frame.size.width / 24;
    CGFloat y_offset = self.view.frame.size.height - ((2 * height)+(2 * x_offset));
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width - (2 * x_offset);
    return CGRectMake(x_offset, y_offset, width, height);
}

#pragma mark - Getters and Setters

- (UILabel *)appLabel
{
    if (!_appLabel){
        _appLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _appLabel.text = @"iOS APP";
        _appLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [_appLabel setFont:[UIFont appThinTitleFont]];
        _appLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return _appLabel;
}

- (UIButton *)signUpButton
{
    if (!_signUpButton){
        _signUpButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        _signUpButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkBlueColor];
        [_signUpButton setTitle:@"SIGN UP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_signUpButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont largeRegularButtonFont]];
        [_signUpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signupPageSegue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _signUpButton;
}

- (UIButton *)loginButton
{
    if (!_loginButton){
        _loginButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        _loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _loginButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        _loginButton.layer.borderWidth =1.0f;
        [_loginButton setTitle:@"LOGIN" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_loginButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont largeRegularButtonFont]];
        [_loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginPageSegue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _loginButton;
}

#pragma mark - Targets

- (void)signupPageSegue
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignUpSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)loginPageSegue
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self];
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spend some time to learn auto-layout. You will be glad you did.

The layout you have shown can be expressed with much more simplicity in Interface Builder, and more importantly, will be more easily updated as new requirements surface.

While it's true that this particular screen, as it is, will work. You will quickly learn as your app grows that it is too labor-intensive to express everything in code.

Note also that if you ever want to run this app on the iPad, the app won't be able to support multi-tasking.

Comment: Any suggestions on learning interface builder? I understand constraints programmatically

Comment: What do you mean by new requirements surfacing?

Comment: +1 to this answer, I used to do everything programatically but it is much much better to do this type of thing in storyboards

Comment: "as new requirements surface" is just a way of saying that as you need to add features, for example, the "I forgot my password" button, you can more quickly implement these features.

Comment: The best way to learn about auto-layout is probably to check out the Apple WWDC videos and search around for tutorials. http://www.raywenderlich.com/ is a great source of tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

It took 3 mins to start a new project and build this screen using auto layout in storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you should use constraint because :

1)Their are simply then "frames"

2)You will have problems with different screen resolution 4s/5s,5,5c/
if you are not use autolayout your app automaticly will increase of screen(6/6+) and people with some exp. will be noticed this mistake, because its really mistake and professionals don't do like this.

3)Your code will decrease twice.

4) You say "I don't like to use interface builder" what is that? like/not like? You should to use all power of UIKit, you can't do as you want,  you  work should effectively... And you should use IB + constraints ...

Please, spend time and learn how to use constraints, it really isn't difficult.